# How can I modify the read-only outputs of an Autoencoder object?

Tags: matlab, properties, setter, autoencoder, readonly-attribute

I get an object of class type `Autoencoder` after running the specified function:

```
[X,T] = wine_dataset;
hiddenSize = 25;
autoenc1 = trainAutoencoder(X,hiddenSize,...
                            'L2WeightRegularization',0,...
                            'SparsityRegularization',0,...
                            'SparsityProportion',1,...
                            'DecoderTransferFunction','purelin');
```

If I try to query one of the properties, I can get it without problem,

```
>> autoenc1.EncoderWeights(1,1)  

ans = -0.0404
```

However, if I try to set it, I get an error:

```
>> autoenc1.EncoderWeights(1,1) = 0.4 

In class 'Autoencoder', no set method is defined for Dependent property 'EncoderWeights'. A 
Dependent property needs a set method to assign its value.
```

Comment: Please add code showing how the `Autoencoder` object is created.

Comment: >> [X,T] = wine_dataset;
>> hiddenSize = 25;
>> autoenc1 = trainAutoencoder(X,hiddenSize,...
'L2WeightRegularization',0,...
'SparsityRegularization',0,...
'SparsityProportion',1,...
'DecoderTransferFunction','purelin');
>> autoenc1.EncoderWeights(1,1)

ans =

   -0.0404

>> autoenc1.EncoderWeights(1,1) = 0.4
IN CLASS 'AUTOENCODER', NO SET METHOD IS DEFINED FOR DEPENDENT PROPERTY 'ENCODERWEIGHTS'.  A DEPENDENT
PROPERTY NEEDS A SET METHOD TO ASSIGN ITS VALUE.

Answer (score 0):

#### Why are you getting this problem?

To understand this behaviour we should take a look inside the [`Autoencoder`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/deeplearning/ref/autoencoder-class.html) class (`\MATLAB\R20###\toolbox\nnet\nnet\nnnetwork\Autoencoder.m`). We can see the following:

- `'EncoderWeights'` is defined inside a `properties(SetAccess = private, Dependent)` block.
- A public "getter" method is defined for this property: `function val = get.EncoderWeights(this)`.

Thus, we see that `'EncoderWeights'` is neither a publicly settable field, nor is there a public setter method for it - so it's not surprising you're getting an error. BTW, on R2018b the error might be a bit more informative:

```
You cannot set the read-only property 'EncoderWeights' of Autoencoder.
```

(If you are unfamiliar with the concepts I used above, I suggest you read about [classes in MATLAB](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/object-oriented-programming-in-matlab.html).)

#### How to solve it?

You can use the [`network()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/deeplearning/ref/autoencoder.network.html) method of you `Autoencoder` object to get a [`network`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/deeplearning/ref/network.html) object, then customize it as you please. In your case you would assign the new weight(s) into `net.IW{1}`. Afterwards you can `train`, `sim` etc.